# OS/X fsck_hfs: "operation not permitted NO WRITE" for external drive in single-user mode

Tags: external-hard-drive, fsck, macos-catalina

I am attempting to repair an external hard drive *(backup drive)* on OS/X Catalina by booting into single-user mode and executing the following command:

```
fsck_hfs -fyd /dev/disk2s2
```

(I determined the identity of the failing disk by looking at the log in Console.)

The Console log says *"this volume could not be verified completely"* in the log output, but gives no further details.  That's why I'm trying to run it in single-user mode with the `-d` flag.

Here's what I get:

```
/dev/disk2s2 ... (NO WRITE)
Operation not permitted.
```

How do I get `fsck_hfs` to consent to run against this drive?

Comment: Why from single user? Why not just from the running OS?

Answer (score 7):

Finally realizing that, since this is an *external* drive, I don't need to go into single-user mode, I logged on as an administrator and used the `sudo` command from the terminal.

First, I tried:

```
 sudo diskutil repairdisk disk2
 sudo diskutil repairvolume disk2s2
```

I noticed that this actually invokes `fsck_hfs` and that the device name includes an `"r"` to be `/dev/rdisk2s2`.

First, I read the manual-entry on the command to see what parameters to use:

```
 man fsck_hfs
```

Then, I ran the command with debug information turned on, and it worked:

```
 sudo fsck_hfs -ryd /dev/rdisk2s2
```

Although this still does not answer why I was getting `NO WRITE` in single-user mode ... an answer that I would still like to receive ... it does mean that I found a solution to my immediate issue.

*(Note:*  MacOS automatically started its own `fsck_hfs` process in the background shortly after I attached the drive.  I used `top` to find the process-id and then used `sudo kill <pid>` to terminate it so that the drive was no longer "busy" and my terminal-command could run against it.)

Comment: You have literally saved me. I’ve tried pretty much all the suggested solutions on the internet, but this is the only one that I’ve been able to start fsck on my external drive. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same as above. 

I will add that killing the OS-initiated fsck will also remount the drive readonly, allowing for files to be accessed (copied off, etc)

Comment: The auto starting fsck check is the thing that threw me off too. Disk Utility was complaining it couldn’t repair the disk, but it turns out that's because the background task is already running. Killing the automatic fsck task then allowed the drive to mount (it was marked as 'unmountable before), and then I could run a normal Disk Utility check on it, which appears to now work fine!

Comment: The pure gold in this answer is the note at the end about killing the auto-spawned fsck process. OMG thanks!